# How can I get Android Lint to show the results only for the current project?

Tags: android, eclipse, lint

I have a few projects in my Eclipse workspace and the Android Lint warnings tab shows the errors and warnings in all the projects.

Is there any way I can filter the results so that I only see the warnings and errors of the current project?

The "problems" tab works as desired in this case and the Lint warnings and errors appear there as well, but the errors are not so descriptive and there's no "go to lint warning description" function.

Cheers.

Comment: Close the other projects?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question - in Java in the problems view one has many options : http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=6140749javaScopedWarnings.jpg. Why not (or where) is analogous for lint ?

Comment: Same problem here. It's quite hard to filter out my own problems as the Google Play SDK and ActionBarSherlock cause quite some lint messages.

@artbristol That's not helpfull... You can't close your project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found for this is to use the Problems View and Configure Contents there to [show problems from elements of the current project](http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=6140749javaScopedWarnings.jpg) (and probably only Lint warnings)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for future reference:

Running lint checks all projects but clearing lint markers(Android Tools >> Clear Lint Markers) works on a single project.

So a simple workaround is to run lint and clear lint markers of all projects except the current one.